# No free clustering with IBM API Connect?

Tags: node.js, strongloop, apiconnect

I was about to use Strongloop for restructuring a Node.JS project when I saw that they are integrating Strongloop into IBM API Connect. The official page even points there.

However from a brief look at features, I saw that the IBM API gateway in contrast to Strongloop Arc (actually Strong Process manager) does not offer free clustering capabilities when deploying the program as PM did. It is mentioned as a paid feature...

I believe this is quite a setback, integrating a good product and limiting its open sourced services...

Answer (score 2):

The API Gateway is different / separate from StrongPM and Arc in general. Some of the features previously available in Arc are now also part of API Connect's API Designer.

If you build an app on top of the LoopBack framework (which still is and should remain OSS), you can deploy that in whatever manner you wish with full clustering.

For example, you could deploy to Bluemix as a Node.js application and run multiple instances of your app for clustering / high-availability.

Or, you could deploy your application using StrongPM on your own hardware and get clustering that way.

If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify and I'll do what I can to provide updates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you are saying about running the app as a separate node application. I am talking about the deploy and monitor tools which in order to use you had to `slc start` in strongloop. So I can use pm without installing strongloop? Since I only saw that SLC command line tool was used I thought it was only in strongloop packet. So if I only install strong-pm I have access to slc or is it used differently???

Comment: Please note that I am also referring to process clustering in the same instance with multiple cores that strong pm handled and comparing it to new apiconnect tool. Since as stated in the offical page of strongloop, you now have to use apic loopback to create and apic start to run your app. So, combining it with strong-pm should require to use both apic and slc???

Comment: You can still get `slc` via the `strongloop` package on npm. Strong PM is still available via the usual methods as well. Via that, you can still achieve clustering as before. Usage of the `apic` command is not required.